# Calculating eigenvalues and eigenstates of an infinite dimensional Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

> Consider the Hamiltonian, $$H = E_{0} \sum_{m = - \infty}^{\infty}(|m⟩⟨m + 1| + h.c.),$$
> where $E_{0}$ is an energy scale, $|m⟩$ are kets which can be used to form a complete basis and h.c. denotes
> Hermitian conjugate. Find out the eigenvalues of $H$. Next, carry out the same analysis for
> $$H' = H − E_{0}m|m⟩⟨m|.$$ Compare the eigenfunctions in the two cases.

Now, in order to find out the eigenvalues of the first Hamiltonian, I need to get $\lambda$ where,

$$ \det(H - \lambda I) = 0$$

This means I need to find the determinant of an infinite dimensional matrix that has only 3 non-zero diagonals - the main one ($-\lambda$), and the ones above and below this one ($E_{0}$). We have a recursion relation here,
$$ \det(T_{n}) = -\lambda \det(T_{n-1}) + E_{0} \det(T_{n-2})$$

This is where I am stuck. I tried this - the matrix is infinite, which means in principle it shouldn't make a difference to the determinant if I remove (or add) a couple of rows and columns, i.e., as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\det(T_{n}) = \det(T_{n-1}) = \det(T_{n-2})$. This gives me $\lambda = E_{0} - 1$. But I am not sure if this is correct.

If I use this same technique for the next Hamiltonian too, then I get $\lambda_{n} = E_{0}(n+1) - 1$. Once again, I have no idea if this is correct.

As for the eigenfunctions, all I can say after this is that in the first case we have an infinite fold degeneracy while this is not the case for the second one. But that is all, I cannot proceed beyond this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did look up tridiagonal matrices - however, nothing came up that helped me. In the finite dimensional case, the answer is sines/cosines but I don't see how to go about it here.

Comment: In fact, I do have reservations about setting the determinants equal - in the second case at least, shouldn't the $n$ in the expression blow up as well in the limit?

Comment: Where is this task from?

Comment: The matrix representation of your Hamilton is a tri-band Toeplitz matrix. Much is known about their spectrum for asymptotically large dimension.

Comment: @TobiasFünke This was in one of our assignments (advanced quantum mech course).

Comment: $H'$ is unbounded from below, which is nonphysical. Also, I believe it's eigenstates will be highly nontrivial

Comment: @SmallPieceOfBread Yes, I agree. The task seems highly non-trivial. Also the wording is weird: We should be able to arrive at the result from previous considerations, which I however fail to see. I wonder if this is a typo and the $m$ in the last sum should be neglected (which would make the task trivial).

Comment: @TobiasFünke It seems there is no sum in that last term - not sure which $m$ is $m$, but the sum is absent.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Sure, I'll do that. I think the question is sort of incomplete and/or not framed properly.

Comment: The hamiltonian $H"$ is that of the *Wannier Stark ladder.* See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0111132.pdf See eqs 1.10 and 1.11 for the eigenvalues and eigenstates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following procedure is only on a formal level. Let $k\in [-\pi,\pi)$ and define $$|k\rangle :=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb Z} e^{ikm}|m\rangle  \tag 1 \quad .$$

Note that $|k\rangle$ in a strict sense is not an element of the underlying Hilbert space but should be interpreted as a "generalized" vector. We compute
$$\langle m|\left(\int_{[-\pi,\pi)} |k\rangle\langle k|\, \mathrm dk\right)|m^\prime\rangle= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{[-\pi,\pi)}e^{ik(m-m^\prime)}\, \mathrm d k = \delta_{m,m^\prime} = \langle m|m^\prime\rangle \quad , $$

which means that

$$ \mathbb I= \int_{[-\pi,\pi)} |k\rangle\langle k|\, \mathrm dk\tag{2} \quad .$$

On the other hand, we have that
$$ \langle k|k^\prime\rangle= \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb Z}e^{im(k-k^\prime)} = \sum\limits_{n\in \mathbb Z} \delta(k-k^\prime - 2\pi n) \quad ,\tag{3}$$

by an instance of Poisson's summation formula. Now note that $k-k^\prime$ can only be a multiple of $2\pi$ if $k=k^\prime$, in which case the RHS gives a single $\delta(0)$; but if $k\neq k^\prime$ the RHS of $(3)$ vanishes. I guess it is more or less legitimate to thus summarize $(3)$ by
$$\langle k|k^\prime\rangle  = \delta(k-k^\prime) \quad . \tag{4} $$

---

With this in mind, you can express the Hamiltonian in this new generalized basis, which will yield
$$ H=2 E_0 \int_{[-\pi,\pi)} \cos(k)\,|k\rangle\langle k|\,\mathrm dk \quad . \tag 5$$

Comment: Isn't it the case that you can include the extra "$2\pi$ shifts" without changing the eigenvalue due to the periodicity of the cosine (possible degeneracy but no change to the spectrum)?

Comment: @nox Do you refer to equation $(3)$? Yes, I guess so. But I want the basis to be "orthonormal", just in the sense of e.g. the plane waves of the free particle.

Comment: Thanks! I can follow the steps, and (5) shows we get a diagonal Hamiltonian in the $k$ basis. Am I right about that?

Comment: @ShKol Yes, indeed- the Hamiltonian is diagonal in that (generalized) basis so you can read-off the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions! I think you would formally arrive at the same results from the finite-dimensional case and then take the thermodynamic limit.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative, more direct method of determining eigenstates and eigenvalues (the situation is complicated by the fact that the eigenstates are not normalisable - see (3) in Tobias Fünke's answer).

Firstly note that the Hamiltonian has a (parity) symmetry. Define an operator, $\widehat{O}$, by its action on the basis states:
$$\widehat{O}|n\rangle = |-n\rangle$$
and note that
$$ \begin{align}
\widehat{O}\widehat{H}\widehat{O}^{\dagger} &= E_{0}\sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} |-m\rangle \langle-(m+1)| + |-(m+1)\rangle \langle -m| \\
 &=  E_{0}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} |n\rangle \langle n-1)| + |n-1\rangle \langle n| \\
&=  E_{0}\sum_{m = -\infty}^{\infty} |m+1\rangle \langle n)| + |m\rangle \langle m+1| \\
&= \widehat{H}\,,
\end{align}  $$
where we made several shifts in the summation variables. $\widehat{O}$ is also unitary; thus $[\widehat{O}, \widehat{H}] = 0$ commute and can be simultaneously diagonalised) - their eigenvalues become the good quantum numbers of the eigenstates. Moreover, since $\widehat{O}$ satisfies
$$\widehat{O}^{2}|n\rangle = \widehat{O}|-n\rangle = |n\rangle$$
we have $\widehat{O}^{2} = \mathbb{1}$. Hence if $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvalue of $\widehat{O}$, so that $\widehat{O}|\Psi\rangle = \lambda|\Psi\rangle$  then
$$|\Psi\rangle  = \widehat{O}^{2}|\Psi\rangle = \lambda\widehat{O}|\Psi\rangle = \lambda^{2}|\Psi\rangle $$
so that $\lambda^{2} =  1 \Longrightarrow = \lambda = \pm 1$. We denote these eigenstates by $|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle$ where $\widehat{O}|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle = \pm|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle$.

Note, by the way, that in (5) of Tobias Fünke's answer, the Hamiltonian is diagonal in the basis $|k\rangle$ but these basis states do *not* have definite parity under $\widehat{O}$. This tension is resolved below.

Now let's seek eigenstates of $\widehat{H}$ in the form
$$ |\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}|n\rangle\,. $$
Asking that $\widehat{H}|\Psi\rangle = E|\Psi\rangle$ equates to
$$ \begin{align}E_{0}\sum_{n} a_{n} |n-1\rangle + a_{n} |n+1\rangle = E\sum_{n}a_{n}|n\rangle \\
\Longrightarrow E_{0}\sum_{n} \big[a_{n+1} + a_{n-1}\big] |n\rangle = E\sum_{n}a_{n}|n\rangle \end{align} $$
from which we obtain a recurrence relation for the coefficients:
$$ a_{n+1} - \frac{E}{E_{0}}a_{n} + a_{n-1} = 0\,. $$
This recursion relation with constant coefficients can be solved by a trial solution $a_{n} = a^{n}$. Substituting provides the characteristic equation for $a$:
$$ a^{n-1}\big[a^{2} - \frac{E}{E_{0}}a + 1\big] = 0 $$
which is solved by
$$ a^{\pm} = \frac{E}{2E_{0}}\bigg(1 \pm \sqrt{1 - \Big(\frac{2E_{0}}{E}\Big)^{2}}\bigg) \,.$$
The general solution is then $a_{n} = A a^{+\,n} + B a^{-\,n}$. We can obtain boundary conditions by looking at the recursion relation about $n = 0$:
$$ \begin{align} a_{1} + a_{-1} &= \frac{E}{E_{0}}a_{0}  \\ \Longrightarrow a_{2} + a_{-2} &= \Big(\frac{E}{E_{0}}\Big)^{2}\Big(1 - 2\Big(\frac{E_{0}}{E}\Big)^{2} \Big)a_{0} \,.\end{align}$$
We also ask for $|\Psi\rangle$ to have definite parity under the operator $\widehat{O}$ defined above:
$$ \widehat{O}|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{n}a_{n}|-n\rangle =  \sum_{n}a_{-n}|n\rangle  $$
so the definite parity eigenstates satisfy
$$ \widehat{O}|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle = \pm |\Psi^{\pm}\rangle\, : \quad  a_{-n}^{\pm} = \pm a_{n}^{\pm}\,.$$

The general solution satisfying these boundary conditions is
$$ a_{n}^{\pm} =\Big(\frac{E}{2E_{0}}\Big)^{n}a\bigg( \bigg( 1 + \sqrt{1 - \Big(\frac{2E_{0}}{E}\Big)^{2}} \bigg)^{n} \pm  \bigg( 1 - \sqrt{1 - \Big(\frac{2E_{0}}{E}\Big)^{2}} \bigg)^{n} \bigg)\,.  $$

Now, although it looks like we have obtained eigenstates / eigenvalues for any $E_{0} \in \mathbb{R}$ we should look at normalisation. So we consider $\big|a_{n}\big|^{2}$ and note that for $|E| \geqslant 2|E_{0}|$ the coefficients $a_{n}$ are real and $\big|a_{n}\big|^{2}$ is growing or is constant. Hence the states are (very!) not-normalisable as $\sum_{n}|a_{n}|^{2}$ diverges. On the other hand, for $E < E_{0}$ the square root becomes imaginary.

Let $\frac{E}{2E_{0}} \equiv \cos(k)$ so that the coefficients of the eigenstates become
$$ \begin{align} a_{n}^{\pm} &= a\Big[ (\cos(k) + i \sin(k))^{n} \pm (\cos(k) - i\sin(k))^{n}\Big]  \\ 
&= a \Big[e^{i k n} \pm e^{-ikn} \Big]\,.
\end{align}$$
The connection with Tobias Fünke's basis should now be becoming clear. Indeed, the eigenstates
$$ |\Psi_{k}^{\pm}\rangle := a\sum_{n} \Big[e^{i k n} \pm e^{-ikn} \Big] |n\rangle $$
are normalised according to
$$ \begin{align} \langle \Psi_{k}^{\pm}| \Psi_{k'}^{\pm}\rangle &= 4\pi|a|^{2} \big[ \delta(k - k') \pm \delta(k + k')\big] \\
\langle \Psi_{k}^{\pm}| \Psi_{k'}^{\mp}\rangle  &= 0\,, \end{align} $$
so we will choose $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}$. These states are normalised in the sense of Dirac, from which we deduce that eigenvalues exist for any $E \in (-2E_{0}, 2E_{0}),$ here parameterised by $k = \arccos(\frac{E}{2E_{0}}) \in (-\pi, \pi)$.

Since the energy $E = 2E_{0}\cos(k)$, the Hamiltonian in this basis is diagonal,
$$\begin{align}
\widehat{H} &= E_{0}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} dk\, \cos(k) \Big[| \Psi_{k}^{+}\rangle \langle \Psi_{k}^{+} |+ | \Psi_{k}^{-}\rangle \langle \Psi_{k}^{-} | \Big] 
\end{align}$$
where we used that $| \Psi_{-k}^{\pm}\rangle = \pm| \Psi_{k}^{\pm}\rangle$. However, note that (due to the parity symmetry) there is a degeneracy of energies, since both $| \Psi_{k}^{\pm}\rangle$ have energy $E_{k} = 2E_{0}\cos(k)$ (it is a two-fold degeneracy because the states transform in irreducible representations of the $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ parity symmetry -- there are only 2, one-dimensional such representations and the Hilbert space collapses into two-fold degenerate subspaces labelled by $k$). We can use this to transform to an equivalent basis by noting that
$$|k\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\big[| \Psi_{k}^{+}\rangle + | \Psi_{k}^{-}\rangle\big]\, \qquad |-k\rangle = \frac{1}{2}\big[| \Psi_{k}^{+}\rangle - | \Psi_{k}^{-}\rangle \big]\,. $$
Indeed, these are the states of Tobias Fünke's answer (up to factor of $\sqrt{2}$ normalisation):
$$ |k\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\sum_{n} e^{ikn}|n\rangle $$
and the Hamiltonian is diagonal:
$$ \begin{align} \widehat{H} &= 2E_{0}\int dk \cos(k) \Big[|k\rangle\langle k| + |-k\rangle\langle -k | \Big]\\
&= 4E_{0}\int dk \cos(k) |k\rangle\langle k| \end{align}$$
where $\langle k | k' \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\delta(k - k')$ and we used the symmetry of the integrand wrt $k$. Now we see Tobias' states and read off the spectrum as $4E_{0} \cos(k) \times \frac{1}{2} = 2E_{0}\cos(k)$ for $k \in (-\pi, \pi)$.

*Note:* Had I chosen $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ my states would have been normalised as in Tobias' answer and our Hamiltonians would coincide.

Comment: What a lovely answer!

Comment: Thank you! I was inspired by trying to recover your Hamiltonian :-)